# Sum of Independent Poisson Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

Let $X_k$ be sequence of independent random variables and suppose $X_k$ has Poisson distribution with mean $k^r$.

For which values of $r$, 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n k^r} = 1
\end{equation}
with probability one.

If $r<-1$, then the sum is convergent, hence it seems to converge to a random variable instead a constant.

It looks to me as an application of Strong Law of Large Numbers, however, $X_k$'s are not identically distributed. Do I need  to scale $X_k$'s?

Brief explanation will help a lot, thank you.